# Hapi Hoek prestart error with Hapi 15.0.1

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I've just updated my npm package to version 15.0.1 of Hapi but i'm seeing this PreStart error with Hoek via the Joi plugin.  Please can anyone tell me how this recent update has changed how I should be using Joi from this error?

```
/CoreSystem/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736
throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
^

Error: Cannot add onPreStart (after) extension after the server was initialized
at Object.exports.assert (/CoreSystem/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736:11)
at internals.Plugin._ext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `server.initialize` was already called before the `server.ext({type: 'onPreStart'...`. To solve this, ensure that all `server.ext` lines are executed first before the `server.initialize` is called.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  This was a plugin I registered after the server.register array